# Preserving font size in scalebox

Tags: fontsize, boxes, scaling

I'm using a scalebox around a picture.  There's text inside it.  I'd like the text size to keep constant even if I change the scale factor.

```
\scalebox{0.5}{
  \begin{picture}(360,255)(0,0)%
  \put(0,0){\includegraphics{figures/basic_flow1.pdf}}
  \put(80,180){$\phi_Q$}
  \end{picture}
}
```

What's the best way to do this?  I know that shrinking 24 pt to 12pt doesn't produce an exact copy of the usual 12pt.  So just using a larger font isn't necesarily a good option.

Comment: Why are you using `\scalebox` in the first place? You could adjust the units instead, and also use the `scale` key-value for `\includegraphics`.

Answer (score 4):

So here's the solution:

```
\scalebox{0.5}{
  \begin{picture}(360,255)(0,0)%
  \put(0,0){\includegraphics{figures/basic_flow1.pdf}}
  \put(80,180){\scalebox{2}{$\phi_Q$}}
  \end{picture}
}
```

Just put a new scalebox around the text to undo the scaling.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid setting the picture width by eye; just the placement of the text needs some trials.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e,picture}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\sbox{\tempbox}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image.pdf}}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}% just to be sure
\begin{picture}(\wd\tempbox,\ht\tempbox)
\put(0,0){\usebox{\tempbox}}
\put(80,180){$\phi_Q$}
\end{picture}

\caption{A scaled figure, with unscaled text}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted to avoid setting the width (for what it's worth \columnwidth is a somewhat safer choice).  In this case, I have several figures, all with the same original size for boxes within the figures, but different widths.  Using a uniform figure width would cause different box sizes between the figures.  I suppose I could have just put the scalebox around the includegraphics...

Comment: @Joel You *don't* want `\scalebox`.

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative?  Is there another option besides scalebox that scales by a given amount?  If I have on figure that is 5cm, another that is 6cm and I set their width to be the same, then the figures will be inconsistent - a circle in one figure meaning the same thing as a circle in the other figure will have different sizes.  Better to scale both by the same amount.

Comment: @Joel If you want the width to be the same set the width as I did.

Comment: But if I make the width the same, the figures will not have consistent appearance.

Comment: @Joel I don't understand; but you can use `\sbox{\tempbox}{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{example-image.pdf}}` (or any scale you like) in the code I showed.

Comment: alright - thanks the scale within the includegraphics makes sense.  The problem with setting the width is that I have 4 figures, each with a different width.  But I have an image within them which needs to be the same size for each figure.  So I have to scale consistently.